# Multiple MDM Profile with Different id's on same ipad

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, mdm, airwatch

i've two MDM profile with same id and i want to install two different application from different environment on same device.when i en-roll device it removes previous installed app from device.Is it possible to save my installed app while en -roll another mdm profile?

Answer (score 1):

In the "Apps & Books" section, edit your app and go in the "Deployment" tab. There is an option "Remove on Unenroll". Uncheck it if you want your app to stay after you unenroll the device.

Comment: Note that doing this will remove the benefits of managing that app deployment with MDM.  You will no longer be able to push updates to that app on the device.  Why not simply add the app to the new MDM profile?

Comment: Also, the reason it removes the old app is that you can only have 1 MDM profile active on a device at any given time.